# ¿ Declarar un array bidimensional que contiene un diccionario en Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Necesito crear un array bidimensional que contega un diccionario. Lo he declarado de esta manera pero me tira error

```
var miArray = [String: AnyObject][ ][ ]
```

Para rellenerlo seria:

```
miArray[columna][linea] = ["llave1":"dato1", "llave2":"dato2"]
```

Cuantas maneras o formas habria para declaralo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes declarar el array como:

```
var miArray: Array< Array< Dictionary<String, String> > >
```

o de forma más corta como:

```
var miArray: [ [ [String: String] ] ]
```

Para inicializarlo usas una expresión igual a la anterior:

```
miArray = [ [ ["llave1":"dato1", "llave2":"dato2"] ] ]
```

o puedes cargar elementos de a uno:

```
miArray.append( [] )
miArray[0].append( ["llave1":"dato1", "llave2":"dato2"] )
```

Luego puedes acceder a un elemento del array de esta forma:

```
let d = miArray[0][0]    // d es un diccionario con valor ["llave1":"dato1", "llave2":"dato2"]
```

Comment: Cual seria la forma mas correcta de declararlo ? De la forma corta o larga ?

Comment: Tengo otro problema al ir rellenando el array que sera [n][m] valores con longitud variable a la segunda vez que intento rellenarlo me da un index out of range. Lo he inicializado como var miArray: [ [ [ String : String ] ] ] = [ [ [ "" : "" ] ] ]

Comment: No se puede rellenar sin "append" como indices es decir miArray[n][m] = ["llave1":"dato1", "llave2":"dato2"]

Comment: No hay una forma "correcta" de declararlo, las dos son válidas. Supongo que depende del gusto de cada uno. No se pueden agregar elementos al _array_ sin `append` o `insert(_:at:)`, porque no se pueden dejar elementos libres. Sí podrías crear el _array_ de dimensión N*M en el momento de inicializarlo, y luego modificar los elementos por posición.

Comment: Ok, gracias por la ayuda